# Access Web Service Using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to send SMS using an API through SQL. I'm using the following code, but the @ResponseText is always NULL.

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Declare @Body as varchar(8000) = '{"content": "Test message from SP","to": ["+9999999999999"]}'

Exec sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @Object OUT;
EXEC  sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post','https://platform.clickatell.com/messages', 'false'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Authorization', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @body

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select JSON_Query(@ResponseText,'$.messages')

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: That looks like a wonderful opportunity to move away from this scheme and call the service from client code rather than SQL Server directly. Invoking COM objects from the engine has implications for performance and stability. Limit your SQL Server to what it's best at -- querying relational data. T-SQL is a terrible language to do general programming in.

Comment: To dovetail @JeroenMostert, remember SQL is a special-purpose language designed to do basic set-based retrieval and manipulation on relational data. Use a general-purpose language (C#, Java, Python, Perl, PHP, VB) for more extensive, dynamic programming. Practically any can connect to MSSQL.